# Datagrid is scrolling up on data refresh

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

Here is what is happening:

1. I have a datagrid (which I am generating dynamically)
2. If I select a row and edit it (on clicking it opens a pop up and when i save data in that, I just update the data provider of the grid locally).
3. As soon as data provider of datagrid is updated, the datagrid scrolls up in a way so that selected row comes at the top of datagrid.

Has someone ever crossed this issue?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using a

```
dataProvider.refresh();
```

Consider changing this to

```
dataProvider.itemUpdated(item);
```

The `.refresh()` sends a 'refresh' type event that causes the dataGrid to change. The `itemUpdated(item)` method does not dispatch this event.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried that, still the same error. Well one thing I would mention here is that somewhere in code on a "find" functionality I am scrol;ling the datagrid to selectedIndex but that is totally indepened and break point never hits that when I am updating the datagrid this way. I know you would like to see the code probably - but its really long...

Comment: Sorry, I'd love to offer more assistance but that's the only idea I have based on the information you've given.

Comment: I am so so sorry... it actually worked the trick. I just needed to remove refresh from everywhere. Wow that was like the quickest resolution ever. Thanks again...